# Return a new version of Eloquent for JSON model after deleting a relationship

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a method that removes a `Photo` model from a `Blog` model. (`Blog` hasMany `Photo`). I do this through AJAX. And my method looks like this:

```
public function removeImage(RemoveImageRequest $request)
    {
        $parent = $this->model->findOrFail($request->parent);

        // Check if a passed image belongs to the passed post
        if(in_array($request->image, $parent->photos->lists('id')->all())) {
            $this->repository->detachPhoto($parent, $request->image);
        }

        return $this->transformer->transform($parent);
    }
```

Transformer is just a class that reformats the data for JSON, in a more readable way, plus adding some additional properties that are used on the front end.

But when I return that `$parent` object, it still has the recently deleted photo. Should I fetch the whole model again or is there a way to return a fresh `copy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload parent's **photos** relation by calling:

```
$parent->load('photos');
```

Afterwards, the relation will hold what is currently in the database - the list of photos without the one you just removed.